# prevent refresh on submit and clear input after submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to build a website that can make people post things and comments on it
now I have some problems
I hope that I could submit the comment without refreshing the page (I found a way to solve this problem but the input won't be cleared)
I already search a lot of information about preventing refresh page on submit but there is no one works for me
and I hope that someone can help me with another problem
I want to make the website show the comment immediately after posting it (without refreshing the page)

directly edit my code and paste on here will be appreciated

below is my index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'db.php';


require_once 'new_tdb.php';

//$datas = get_publish_article();

if(isset($_COOKIE["mcsh"])){
}else{
  header("Location: ../mcsh/login/index.php");
  exit();
}

?>
<html>
<head>
        <title>
    website
    </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    <?php include 'menu.css' ?>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include 'menu.php' ?>
        
        <center>
        <font class="corn-blue">
        
        </font>
        </center>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <?php
$bij = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `comment` != 1 order by id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $bij);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$post_id = $row['id'];
$ins = $row['ins'];
$s_uid = $row['s_uid'];
$p_id = $row['id']; 
//$selc = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_id` = $p_id";
?>
<center>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
        Poster: <?php echo $s_uid;?>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $ins;?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <details>
    <summary>Comment</summary>
    <form id="worker" action="comment.php" method="post" target="the_iframe">
                                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
                                <p><input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Comment......"> <input type="submit" hidefocus="true" name="submit"></p>
                                </form>
                                <iframe id="is_iframe" name="the_iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
                                <?php 
                                $sel = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id order by id DESC";
                                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);
                                $rows2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
                                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                                    $ins2 = $row2['ins'];
                                    $poster2 = $row2['s_uid'];
                                ?>
                                <p><?php echo $poster2 . ': ' . $ins2; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
</details>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                                </center>
                                <h1>
                                    -
                                </h1>
<?php
}
            ?>
                           
                                    <?php if (empty($row['file'])){
                                    
                                    }else{   
echo('<img src="image/'); echo $row['file']; echo('"width="100%" height="auto">');
                                         }
                                    ?>


                    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to use AJAX if you want to submit without refreshing.

Comment: Please focus on one problem at a time.  Which of the problems in your question are you currently trying to correct?  What specific attempt have you made to correct it?  What didn't work as expected?

Comment: Do not use `<font>` tags

Answer (score -1):

As @Barmar said you want to use AJAX for Asynchronous actions in your website. Submit event must refresh the page to resend the new form data.

PHP is synchrony, what means if you want to do something with synchronous codes you will need to refresh the whole page.

**Lear Further :** [Javascript documentation of Ajax by mozila here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)